# Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.10 on Toshiba Satellite C55D with UEFI boot mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, uefi, toshiba-laptop

I am trying to get Ubuntu 14.10 to boot on my Toshiba Satellite C55D-B5212.  I have UEFI boot mode and Secure Boot enabled.  The Ubuntu live USB stick booted without issues and the install seemed to go through without any issues.  However, when I rebooted the laptop I got a message asking me to reboot and select the proper boot device.

I used the Boot-Repair-Disk which attempted to repair the boot issue and provided me with the following link:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10788775/

I was able to verify that the proper files exist in the EFI System Partition and that there is a boot entry in the UEFI boot table pointing to the correct file.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, try disabling Secure Boot. Although Ubuntu *should* work with Secure Boot enabled, there are occasional bits of flakiness that cause problems, so it's worth trying it with Secure Boot disabled.

Second, I note the following from your Boot Repair output:

```
efibootmgr -v
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    Vendor(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb,)
Boot0001* UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(2,3)PCI(0,0)MAC(f8a963c13bd7,0)IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0, 0..BO
Boot0002* UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(2,3)PCI(0,0)MAC(f8a963c13bd7,0)030d3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000..BO
```

That `ubuntu` entry looks a bit weird. Ordinarily, it would look something like this:

```
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,c00,114000,6e49fcaf-d054-47c9-ba69-a668c5ee8192)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

Note that this includes a path to a file, starting with the hard disk (`HD(...)`). Yours lacks that, which suggests some sort of problem. You might try manually adding a boot entry with `efibootmgr` in Linux, as in:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi -L MyUbuntu
```

This command should create a new entry called `MyUbuntu`. Note the doubled-up backslashes (`\\`) used as directory separators in the path to `shimx64.efi`. After you type this command, use `efibootmgr -v` to view the results; you should see a new entry that includes the path to `shimx64.efi`, and its number should be first on the `BootOrder` line. If that all looks good, then reboot and hope it works.

If the boot fails at this point and `efibootmgr -v` shows that the entry you created has changed, you could try creating the entry in an EFI shell program. This process is a little involved, but in brief:

1. You must obtain a version 2 EFI shell. [This binary](https://edk2.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/edk2/trunk/edk2/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi) works well for most recent computers.
2. You must set it up so you can launch the shell. Copying it to a FAT partition on a USB flash drive as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` should enable you to boot into it. As an alternative to these first two steps, you can download a USB flash drive or CD-R version of [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a boot medium, and boot it. These versions of rEFInd include an EFI shell binary that you can launch from the second row of icons.
3. In the shell, type `bcfg boot dump -b` to see the existing entries. Pay attention to the numbers, since you'll need to create an entry using a number that's not already in use.
4. Create a new entry by typing `bcfg boot add 4 fs0:\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi "Ubuntu (shell)"`, changing `4` to a number that's not in use. Note the backslashes used as directory separators. Also note this assumes that `fs0:` is your ESP. (You can double-check this by typing `fs0:` and then using `dir` or `ls` to view its contents.) This creates an entry with a name `Ubuntu (shell)` in the menu. (That name is arbitrary; change it as you see fit.)
5. Type `bcfg boot mv 4 0`, changing `4` to whatever number you used in the previous step. This sets the new entry as the default.
6. Type `reset` to reboot the computer.

If this procedure fails, then your firmware is **very** badly broken. If the computer is brand new, I recommend returning it to the store and contacting Toshiba to tell them why you returned it. Manufacturers will keep selling junk if people don't complain, and returning junk is the only way we have to complain that will get any attention at all.

If the above procedures fail and you can't return the computer, you could try copying the contents of `EFI/ubuntu` on the ESP to `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` (you'll need to create that directory) and rename `shimx64.efi` to `bootmgfw.efi`. You may then need to create a boot entry with `efibootmgr` or `bcfg`, as just described. As you might guess, `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` is the usual name of the Windows boot loader. Unfortunately, some badly broken EFIs won't boot anything else. Boot Repair can also set this up, although I believe you need to select an option on the Advanced menu to do it.